# Visual Studio 2017 - Message filter indicated that the application is busy

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, envdte

I'm porting over a small console application that deletes files on disk that are not in a Visual Studio project. This code worked in Visual Studio 2013, but I'm receiving the following error when I ran it in Visual Studio 2017:

> **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:** 'The message filter
>   indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))'

**Current Code:**

```
public static int DeleteFilesNotInProject(string solutionFileAndPath, string projectName, string extension)
    {
        var returnValue = 0;
        EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;

        // Targets Visual Studio 2017
        dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0", true), true);

        MessageFilter.Register();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        while (!dte.Solution.IsOpen)
        {
            // make sure it is ready to open
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            dte.Solution.Open(solutionFileAndPath);
        }

        dte.Solution.Open(solutionFileAndPath);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
        {
            if (project.UniqueName.EndsWith(projectName))
                foreach (string s in GetFilesNotInProject(project, extension))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(s);
                    File.SetAttributes(s, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Delete(s);
                    returnValue++;
                }
        }

        dte.Quit();

        MessageFilter.Revoke();

        return returnValue;
    }
```

The exception is thrown on the `while (!dte.Solution.IsOpen)` line. I tried commenting that out and then it is thrown on the `foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)` line instead.

Notes:

- The code is based on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx). I'm looking to keep this in a Console Application.
- I found PowerShell, and VS Addons/Extensions, but I'm interested in keeping this a C# class called withing a Console Application.
- I tried using just the EnvDTE, instead of EnvDTE80 but received the same error.

Comment: it seems that the DTE instance is busy. Is there a way of checking if it's ready before it's used? Have you tried even accessing it before the while loop?

Comment: I tried removing the while loop and received the same message on the next line that uses it. I also tried running the exe with the solution closed, same error.

Comment: Did you remember to attribute `Main` method with `[STAThread]`?

Comment: I don't have that attribute on it, would it have worked in VS2013 without it?

Comment: Every implementation of the IOleMessageFilter that I have seen indicates that it is required and your link also states: "To do this, initiate the new thread from your Visual Studio application in a single-threaded apartment (STA) and surround your automation code with the IOleMessageFilter handler."  C# console applications default to MTA.

Comment: @TnTinMn, that was it. I confirmed the old app didn't have it but it was an older setup (last used about 5 years ago). If you post your response as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of the IOleMessageFilter registered using the [CoRegisterMessageFilter function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693324(v=vs.85).aspx) must be in a STA apartment thread.

From the CoRegisterMessageFilter function documentation:

> Only one message filter can be registered for each thread. Threads in
>   multithreaded apartments cannot have message filters.

Your question stated that you are *porting over a small console application* and indicates that you are using C#.  I don't know exactly what *porting* implies, but if the original code was in VB.Net, VB.Net automatically marks Console applications with the [STAThreadAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) where-as C# does not and as such the thread is created in a MTA thread.

In C#, you apply the attribute to the entry method (`Main`) as shown below.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar issue to this question. I added the STAThread attribute as directed in the accepted answer but in addition to getting the `RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER` exception, I also got the `RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED` exception as well. After some googling I came across the following MS document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms228772(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The above doc from MS states that to avoid these errors we can implement a COM message filter (IOleMessageFilter) that simply tells the COM interface to retry if we get the `RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED` message and wait if we get `RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER` message.

Hope this helps someone who is lost.